# bound check for iterator in Release mode (c++)

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I intentionally made iterator to exceed the size of `std::vector` like,

```
for (std::vector <Face>::iterator f = face.begin();
          f!=face.end()+5;
               ++f)
{
    // here I try to access (*f).P
    // note that I added 5 to the face.end()
}
```

I did not face any error neither during compiling and run-time. How can I prevent that?

Comment: Just don't do that? As for detection, search for *checked iterators*.

Comment: Debug builds usually catch that

Comment: I use Release because of a need for run-time performance.

Comment: @Shibli: You need to use **both** configurations.  There's a reason one is called "Debug", and the other is called "Release".  You don't want to give up the extra debug tests until you're ready to release.

Comment: I have not thought that before. It gave a run-time error in debug. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want checked access to `vector` elements, you may use the `at` function which throws `std::out_of_range` exception in case of boundary violation. Example:

```
for (std::vector<Face>::size_type i = 0;
          i != face.size()+5;
               ++i)
{
    face.at(i).f();
}
```

The standard doesn't specify any checked iterators. The wording in the standard is that access to an invalid iterator results in undefined behavior. But many implementations provide checked iterators. If portability is not a concern, you may use one of those checked iterators. For example, in MSVC Debug mode, `vector<T>::iterator` is a checked iterator. In Release mode, however, it's just a typedef for `T*`

Comment: In debug mode, it spots the error without using `at`. Since I did not understand your last sentence, in release mode should I use `at` for checking?

Comment: @Shibli: The checking isn't for free. If you want an exception to be thrown, then you should use at. If you know that all your boundaries are correct and do not wish to have extra checking overhead, then do not use at.

Answer (score 1):

What C++ compiler are you using?
VC10 (i.e. the C++ compiler in VS2010) in debug build correctly identifies the problem:

```
// Compile with:
// cl /EHsc /W4 /nologo /D_DEBUG /MDd test.cpp


#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


class Face
{
public:
    std::string Name;

    explicit Face(const std::string & name)
      : Name(name)
    {}
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<Face> faces;
    faces.push_back( Face("Connie") );
    faces.push_back( Face("John") );

    for (
        std::vector <Face>::iterator f = faces.begin();
        f != faces.end() + 5;
        ++f)
    {
        std::cout << f->Name << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When executing the resulting .exe, an error dialog box is showed with the following error message:

> **Expression: vector iterator + offset out of range**

Comment: @Shibli: You're welcome. The STL implementation that comes with MS Visual C++ is excellent for debug purposes with its checked iterators and debug iterator support.

Answer (score 1):

For a release version of the standard C++ library you won't get build-in bounds checking on your iterators (or other operations which may be unchecked) because it would be comparatively slow. However, this doesn't mean that you need to compile in debug mode: as far as I understand the libstdc++ debug mode it can be used when compiling with compiler optimizations turned on. I would suspect that this true for other checked STL implementations because the checked code is typically just guided by setting up some macros appropriately. To do this you'll need to find the appropriate macro settings and set them up appropriately with whatever you use to build your code.